# Reinforcement Learning. IndexError: index 28 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 4

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, reinforcement-learning

I'm trying to solve a reinforcement learning problem with the current bit of code below. I get an error in this of the code which I've posted below.

```
target_q[batch_index, actions] = rewards + self.gamma * np.max(next_q, axis=1)*dones
```

The values and shapes of the variables are as follows

target_q value is

```
[[-0.10855542 -0.0802312   0.06993277  0.00552639]
```

[-0.09975365 -0.07372604  0.06426253  0.00507834]
[-0.12322513 -0.09107337  0.07938312  0.00627324]
[-0.08215004 -0.06071554  0.05292208  0.00418217]
[-0.10268757 -0.07589445  0.06615258  0.00522767]
[-0.11735719 -0.08673649  0.07560297  0.00597452]
[-0.10855542 -0.0802312   0.06993277  0.00552639]
[-0.07628225 -0.05637873  0.04914192  0.00388342]
[ 0.          0.          0.          0.        ]
[-0.0792161  -0.05854715  0.05103201  0.00403276]] with shape (10, 4)

```
batch_index = np.arange(self.batch_size, dtype=np.int32), with batch size = 10.
```

The value of action is [28 35 45 26 40 33 40 49 34 41], with shape (10, )

The value of the reward is [ 10. -20. -20. -20. -20. 10. -20. -20. -20. -20.] with shape (10, )

The value of gamma is 0.99

The value of next_q is  [[-0.08215004 -0.06071554  0.05292208  0.00418217]
[-0.10855542 -0.0802312   0.06993277  0.00552639]
[-0.10855542 -0.0802312   0.06993277  0.00552639]
[-0.12615901 -0.09324171  0.08127321  0.00642257]
[-0.09975365 -0.07372604  0.06426253  0.00507834]
[-0.0792161  -0.05854715  0.05103201  0.00403276]
[-0.11735719 -0.08673649  0.07560297  0.00597452]
[-0.12322513 -0.09107337  0.07938312  0.00627324]
[-0.07628225 -0.05637873  0.04914192  0.00388342]
[-0.10268757 -0.07589445  0.06615258  0.00522767]], wiit shape (10, 4)

The value of dones is [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1] with shape (10, ).

I'm getting the following error

```
 IndexError: index 28 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 4.
```

Can someone tell me how to solve this error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use an index value that's too large!  28 is larger than 4.  Know your dimensions, and know the indexing valjes.

Comment: What do you suggest I do for this. Can you suggest a work around?

Comment: When asking about an error identify exactly which line has the problem.  Show the traceback.

Comment: Identify the real problem first. Figure out what is producing that `28` index value.